# Sum values based on same keys in dict and make array

Tags: python, django

Hi guys I have data like this

```
[
{
    'name': 'snow 7', 
    'count': 1, 
    'rows_processed': None, 
    'pipelines': 1
}, 
{
    'name': 'snow 6',
    'count': 1,
    'rows_processed': None,
    'pipelines': 1
},
{
    'name': 'snow 6',
    'count': 1,
    'rows_processed': None,
    'pipelines': 1
}, 
{
    'name': 'snow 6',
    'count': 2,
    'rows_processed': None,
    'pipelines': 2
},
{
    'name': 'snow 5',
    'count': 2,
    'rows_processed': 4,
    'pipelines': 2
},
{
    'name': 'snow 4',
    'count': 2,
    'rows_processed': None,
    'pipelines': 2
}]
```

and i want to sum the values of `rows_processed` and `pipelines` based on `name` key like for `snow 6` `pipelines` sum will be 4 and so on, basically the final data should look like this.

```
    {
     "Rows Processed": [0, 0, 4, 0],
     "Pipelines Processed": [1, 4, 2, 2]
    }
```

how can i make data like above?
this is what i have done so for

```
    rows_processed = {}
    pipeline_processed = {}
    for batch in batches:
        for label in batch.keys():
            rows_processed[label] = rows_processed.get(batch['rows_processed'], 0) + batch['rows_processed'] if batch['rows_processed'] else 0
    for batch in batches:
        for label in batch.keys():
            pipeline_processed[label] = pipeline_processed.get(batch['pipelines'], 0) + batch['pipelines'] if \
            batch['pipelines'] else 0
```

Comment: Didn't you just the same question a few minutes back?

Comment: yeah i deleted that question and posted again new one

Comment: You just copy-paste the same content here again. The reason your previous question was closed is because there's no [mcve]. The code you posted is not indented properly and has syntax errors. As mentioned in the [previous post(now deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69681295/sum-values-of-same-keys-from-dict-and-make-array) by MadPhysicist Stack overflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: I forget to mention what i did in previous question and now i have added what i have done so far

Comment: Also i have updated my question with proper formatting now

Comment: Filter your batches by key ```snow6 = [di for di in batches if di['name'] == 'snow6']```. Get counts for what you need: ```processed_rows = [di['processed_rows'] if di['processed_rows'] else 0 for di in snow6]```. Repeat for pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

One way using a two-level [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [Boolean Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>>
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> for batch in batches:
...     d['Rows Processed'][batch['name']] += batch['rows_processed'] or 0
...     d['Pipelines Processed'][batch['name']] += batch['pipelines'] or 0
... 
>>> list(d['Rows Processed'].values())
[0, 0, 4, 0]
>>> list(d['Pipelines Processed'].values())
[1, 4, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I resolved the above question by doing the following code however i'm not sure if this is the right approach or not. If anyone has better approach then please let me know.

```
    rows_processed = {}
    pipeline_processed = {}
    for batch in batches:
        rows_processed[batch['name']] = rows_processed.get(batch['name'], 0) + batch['rows_processed'] if batch['rows_processed'] else 0
    for batch in batches:
        pipeline_processed[batch['name']] = pipeline_processed.get(batch['name'], 0) + batch['pipelines'] if batch['pipelines'] else 0
print(list(rows_processed.values()))
print(list(pipeline_processed.values()))
```